# How to use window functions in sails controller?

Tags: window, sails.js, alert

> PROBLEM : 
>       
>  I want to use window functions in sails controller.
>       
>  window functions like alert, prompt, confirm etc

I have a controller function say myPicUpload(), i want to prompt a alert box saying that "Do you want to convert your pic ?" if Yes do some operations on image otherwise upload without converting.

```
module.exports = {
    myPicupload : function(req, res) {
       if(window.alert("Do you want to convert your pic ?")) {
          // Do Image conversion operations and upload
       }
       else {
          // Upload Image operations
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nohow. `window.alert` or `window.prompt` is client-side functions. Sails is a back-end framework.